# Blank PDF generated

Tags: php, pdf, fpdf

I am using `FPDF` to create a PDF of an invoice.

I am then adding this as an email attachment.

All of this seems be working fine for me, on my Mac, but users on Windows systems, seem to be getting a blank PDF, with no information in it.

PHP calling the attachment to email

```
$EMAIL = $confirmation_customer_email_from;
$EMAIL_NAME = $confirmation_customer_email_from_name;
$mail = new PHPMailer();

require_once('giftaid.php');
$mail->AddAttachment($name, 'giftaid.pdf');

require_once('emails/mail.customer.invoice.php');
if (!$mail->Send()){
  echo 'Mailer error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
}

unlink($name);
```

giftaid.php

```
require('fpdf/fpdf.php');
$image1 = "../images_site/logo.gif";

$pdf= new FPDF();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetMargins(1,1,1,1);
$pdf->cell( 40, 40, $pdf->Image($image1, $pdf->GetX(), $pdf->GetY(), 33.78), 0, 0, 'L', false );
$pdf->SetFont('Helvetica','B',30);
$pdf->cell(150,10,'Gift Aid Declaration',0,0,'R',0);
$pdf->line(102, 20, 199, 20);

$m=microtime(true);
$name = 'temp/'.$m.'.pdf';

$pdf->Output($name, 'F');
```

The PDF looks fine on my mac, using `Preview`, but only dispolays the logo image on windows when opening in Adobe Acrobat.

Does anyone know what the problem could be?

EDIT: It is also blank in Adobe Reader for Mac

Comment: `require('fpdf/fpdf.php');` but speaking about `tcpdf`... how can this be?

Comment: whoops, was supposed to be FPDF. Changed question now.

Comment: Have you tried a different image? Can you try a JPG image?

Comment: The image loads fine. But the code in the `some more code here` section doesn't display. Like a `$pdf->Write()`

Comment: please show more code - where you put image in thepdf file and where you put smoe text after it

Comment: What does e-mail have to do with this? The file looks good it not sent by e-mail?

Comment: try moving `$pdf->Write();` after you set margins and font

Comment: That still only displays the image and nothing else.

Comment: PDF checker results: Error
Document ID missing, Document modification date missing, Document title empty/missing, Font not embedded (13 matches on 1 page), Object uses RGB (1 match on 1 page), OutputIntent for PDF/X missing
PDF/X version key (GTS_PDFXVersion) missing, Page does not have TrimBox or ArtBox (1 match on 1 page), Resolution of color and grayscale images is less than 150 ppi (1 match on 1 page), Trapped key not true or false,

Comment: Just seems odd it opens fine in `Preview`, but not Acrobat. Is there anything else i need to set in the PDF, like a subject, title etc?

Comment: Seems I was missing a `$pdf-setFont()` before I was dispalying the `setCell()`

Answer (score 1):

As commented, it's due to the order of commands used. You can't use `setCell()` before `setFont()`.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use image as the cell content.

```
$pdf->cell( 40, 40, $pdf->Image($image1, $pdf->GetX(), $pdf->GetY(), 33.78), 0, 0, 'L', false );
```

Instead use

```
$pdf->cell( 40, 40, "", 0, 0, 'L', false );
$pdf->Image($image1, $pdf->GetX(), $pdf->GetY(), 33.78);
```

to obtain the same result